# Jquery - Delay on css for preloader not working

Tags: jquery, preloader

I was wondering why the last line `$('body').delay(500).css({'overflow-y':'auto'});` does not delay the change of the css of the body. It is for my preloader. I am very new with Javascript/jquery. Hope someone can help me out. If you got any other tips to improve the script please feel free to do so!

```
$(window).on('load', function() {
  $('#preloader svg').fadeOut(200);
  $('#preloader-container').delay(200).fadeOut(500,'linear'); 
  $('body').delay(500).css({'overflow-y':'auto'});
})
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/delay/: The `.delay()` method is best for delaying between queued jQuery effects. `.css` is not a queued effect

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because `css()` does not use the `fx` queue, so `delay()` has no effect on it.

The simple fix is to use a timeout instead:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').css('overflow-y', 'auto');
}, 500);
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped